# Need recommendations for ways to save data and have it be able to be looked up

Tags: android, save

I'm making a personal project where I need to save a bunch of different instances of a class that I made that right now only contain ints and strings. I'm thinking of making a list of them and just saving that using the File.class methods. I'm not looking to do JSON yet, I'll figure that out later.

If you have any recommendations on how to move forward, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working in Java, Object Serialization would work well for this. Your class can implement Serializable, and be written out to a file. Keep in mind that changes to your class in source code will render that serialized object unusable with the new code. For an example on how to serialize and write Java objects to a file, see [Datsabk's article](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-write-java-object-to-a-file/).